# How to prove that A and B are independent if and only if P(A|B) = P(A).

Tags: statistics

How to prove: 
A and B are independent if and only if P(A|B) = P(A).

What I'm confused about is proving the assertion in both directions... How does one approach that?

Comment: You have to show that $P(A\cap B)= P(A)P(B)$ is equivalent to $P(A^c\cap B^c)= P(A^c)P(B^c)$. Now $P(A)=1-P(A^c)$ and $A^c=\Omega\setminus A$. So they are related.

Comment: Thanks Karl! I'm sorry about switching the question on you.

Comment: I didn't realize I had posted about the wrong one :/

Comment: I had just typed out an answer. Do not like to waste time.  Note that if $\Pr(B)\ne 0$, we define $\Pr(A|B)$ as $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$. So from the previous question we get $\Pr(A|B)=\Pr(A)$. The argument also goes in the other direction, at least in the case $\Pr(B)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is easy to show that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ implies the other three combinations of events $(A,B^c)$, $(A^c,B)$ and $(A^c,B^c)$ are also independent.

1. Now, assume $A$ and $B$ are independent, that is $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ .

$\Rightarrow P(A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = P(A|B)$.

2. Now, assume $P(A|B) = P(A)$,

$\Rightarrow P(A) = P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Cross-multiplying the above equation you can get the result.